# TV during the 3 weeks

Tags: three-weeks

I seem to recall from Igros Moshe that Reb Moshe is *matir* watching TV shows with background music during the 3 weeks, on the basis that the main intention is not to listen to the music.

Does anyone know where this is?

Comment: I found references to the halacha you want quoted by both Moadei Yeshurun and Ohalei Yeshurim, both p. 128, both quoting Rav Moshe Feinstein, zt”l.

Comment: Ohalei Yeshurun*